# How does Ember decide when to rerender component under the hood?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For some reason, our project is setting a component's props inside `didRender` function, which would trigger another rerender based on the lifecycle of Ember component. But this hasn't ended up in an infinite loop except when the previous prop and new prop are both empty arrays. May I know why is that? How does Ember decide when to rerender component under the hood?

someComponent.hbs

```
{{someComponent
    someProps=DS.attr() // THIS IS AN ARRAY
 }}
```

someComponent.js

```
didRender() {
    const newProps = ['newValue'];
    this.set('someProps', newProps)
}
```

So the above example works as excepted (`render -> didRender -> updateProps -> rerender -> didRender -> stop`) when both or either of the previous or current values of `someProps` are NOT empty. But an infinite loop occurs when BOTH of the previous and current values of `someProps` are empty arrays.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you probably use the wrong hook. Have you considered to use `didReceiveAttrs` or a computed property?

Comment: @Lux Yes I did, but the main question here is why does the infinite loop happen only when the previous and current props are both empty arrays?

Comment: what you do is AFAIK unsupported and by definition undefined behaviour so the answer is probably "implementation detail". Generally ember (glimmer) tries to diff your current state with the expected before rerendering.

Comment: @Lux I see. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the two empty arrays are different objects but that the nonempty arrays are the same object?

Comment: @Gaurav I thought about that but I'm sure that the nonempty arrays are different objects as well.